# Can function be differentiable but not continuous?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there any possible function that is not continuous but differentiable?

For example these functions, $f(x) = \pi x + \pi $ whenever $x<0$ ,and $f(x) = \arctan \pi x$ when $0\leq  x$.

I know that these are not continuous but when I derivative them, they get the same answers. Should I consider that differentiable or not?

Comment: Just FYI, this site supports Latex commands. For example `$\pi x$` renders $\pi x$.

Comment: We say a function is differentiable if $ \lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) $ exists at every point $ a $ that belongs to the domain of the function. Verifying whether $ f(0) $ exists or not will answer your question. :)

Comment: @KoByeongmin: That's *not* what differentiable means!

Comment: Isn’t it? Oh well I must have dosed off in my Analysis class :_( (Perhaps I should mention that the definition only works for a function whose domain is an open interval?)

Answer (score 6):

No. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then\begin{align}\lim_{x\to a}f(x)-f(a)&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}(x-a)\\&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\times\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)\\&=f'(a)\times0\\&=0\end{align}and therefore $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. That is, $f$ is continuous at $a$.

In the example that you mention, the left derivative at $0$ doesn't exist.